# Does setting password for account on Windows machine makes it more protected agains web hazards?

Tags: windows, security, internet, passwords

What if I will go out to the Internet through Windows PC without setting passwords on Windows user accounts: no password on admins and other users accounts. Will it make the OS more vulnerable to attacks from the web?

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I have no idea at all what you mean. Could you edit your post and reword it completely so we can understand the question you're trying to get answered?

Comment: @JakeGould so you don't now exactly, it's just thoughts ?

Comment: @Moab I hope now my question became more clear, if not then you should edit it, because man who posted an answer understood me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the password necessary only to prevent another person who sat down
>   at my computer from being able to log in?

The password on a desktop machine or server is mainly dealing with the local user accounts and access.

> Or does the password prevent access via the Internet to PC?

It *could* prevent access to some services from a network but ultimately that is not the main purpose of a local user’s credentials. Most services that one could access over a network would need password as well. And that access is really determined by a myriad of rights and needs connected to that service. Even with a password removed for a local user, there are still things on your PC that could make you vulnerable via networked connection.

For example, you could run a web server (IIS or Apache) and “expose” that to a network or even the Internet. Since websites are basically “read only” what would the risk be? Well, there are some risks since there are tons of exploits out there that could *potentially* hack into your PC via an active web service from the network connection and those “hacks” have nothing to do with local user credentials.

So if your question is about removing a local system’s user password and the risks it presents to you on a network, the answer is one thing has very little to do with the other. Go ahead and just remove a local password or setup your PC to just login automatically as your user when it powers up if you feel comfortable doing that.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@Giacomo1968’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/978297/167207) note following:

Since Windows 8 the default installation tries to connect your local user account with your Microsoft Account (ex: Hotmail/Windows Live account). If you do this then your local user’s password IS your Internet account's password. When you change it on your Login screen, so it also changes on the Internet. Also, such a connected password is not possible to delete.

Addendum:

Everybody who has local access to your computer can boot it with an Live CD and browse through the Hard Drive contents without logging in without Windows even being started. By taking “ownership” of the files they could do what they want. The only real protection here is an encrypted drive (look up [BitLocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/protect-files-bitlocker-drive-encryption))